# on running su from java and on adb i get Activity Manager Crash

Tags: android

I download from git hub su-binary-master.zip
build on android tree {mm}
running on the adb shell it work and i get root id.
On the logcat log I get Activity Manager Crash.

If I run the "SU" from Java the command not work and I get the same error:

```
su      ( 3479): stat failed with 2: No such file or directory
E/JavaBinder( 2757): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 2757): java.lang.RuntimeException: bogus span encoding 7471205
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:768)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:649)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.ClipDescription.<init>(ClipDescription.java:236)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.ClipData.<init>(ClipData.java:869)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.Intent.readFromParcel(Intent.java:6706)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6675)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6666)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6664)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:335)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1674)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
E/JavaBinder( 2757):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/su      ( 3479): request rejected (10036->0 /system/bin/sh)
E/ActivityManager( 2757): Activity Manager Crash
E/ActivityManager( 2757): java.lang.RuntimeException: bogus span encoding 7471205
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:768)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:649)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.ClipDescription.<init>(ClipDescription.java:236)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.ClipData.<init>(ClipData.java:869)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.Intent.readFromParcel(Intent.java:6706)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6675)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6666)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6664)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:335)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1674)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
E/ActivityManager( 2757):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
E/BufferQueue( 2477): [Please wait] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
E/BufferQueue( 2477): [eu.chainfire.libsuperuser_example/eu.chainfire.libsuperuser_example.InteractiveActivity] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
I/ActivityManager( 2757): Displayed eu.chainfire.libsuperuser_example/.InteractiveActivity: +147ms
D/libsuperuser( 3430): [libsuperuser][G][SU%] SHELL_DIED
W/audio_hw_primary( 2480): do_out_standby... 1086139920
W/ThrottleService( 2757): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
I/PowerManagerService( 2757): Going to sleep due to screen timeout...
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2477): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0x411fa318
I/SWITCHPROFILE( 2757): Switchprofile thread received GOV_CONSERVATIVE from Power HAL
D/dalvikvm( 2757): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 227K, 11% free 6888K/7672K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
W/audio_hw_primary( 2480): set parameters screen_state=off
D/dalvikvm( 2757): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 163K, 10% free 6945K/7672K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
D/dalvikvm( 2757): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 9% free 7038K/7672K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
D/PhoneStatusBar( 2828): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back home RECENT* clock SEARCH* >
V/TAG     ( 2757): bug 7643792: fitSystemWindows([0,25][0,0])
E/BufferQueue( 2477): [Keyguard] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
D/PhoneStatusBar( 2828): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT CLOCK* SEARCH >
```